# Python3: How can I return a raw string containing both " and '. I can't figure it out even with raw string (r'') and escape character (\)

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping, rawstring

I have recently started python and am having a frustratingly hard time trying to figure out how to print a raw string containing both ' and " characters. Even with various combinations of r'' and \ I cannot get python to return the literal string that I require.

Goal: Assign string of the following format to variable (similar format to be used as password). String: "1z8'aoVz1+9p}2C    (16 character string starting with " and containing ').

Current result:

```
>>> string ='''"1z8'aoVz1+9p}2C'''
>>> string
    '"1z8\'aoVz1+9p}2C'

>>> string =r'"1z8\'aoVz1+9p}2C'
>>> string
    '"1z8\\\'aoVz1+9p}2C'
```

I have also tried splitting it into several variable and concatenating but python always returns the \ before '.

Thank you all for your help. I have learn a lot from this forum.

Comment: Your first attempt (with triple quotes) works

Comment: Try `print(string)`…

Comment: A "raw string" isn't a data type, and you can't return one. They're just strings. "Raw" is only meaningful with string literals, and then it just impacts how the string literal is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for raw string:

```
string =""""1z8'aoVz1+9p}2C"""
```

Now, if you do this:

```
>>> string =""""1z8'aoVz1+9p}2C"""
>>> string
```

you will get this:

```
'"1z8\'aoVz1+9p}2C'
```

but if you print it, you'll get what you want:

```
"1z8'aoVz1+9p}2C
```